# Multiple listboxes in python dynamically with Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am a beginner in Python.
I wanted to create multiple listboxes and read the entries from the listboxes. The number of list-boxes depends on the size of the list named "result" defined at the start of the code. The length of the list "result" is not a constant. Depending on the selections made in the listboxes further operations need to be formed.

The code I ended up is like:

```
result = ['Weekly','Monthly',Annual]
class Application(Frame):

def __init__(self,master):
    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    for inst in result:



        textenter = "Select the required output format" + inst

        self.Label[inst] = Label(self,text = textenter)
        self.Label[inst].grid(columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

        self.Listbox[inst] = Listbox(self, selectmode = MULTIPLE,exportselection = 0)
        self.Listbox[inst].grid(sticky = W)


        for items in ["Text","XML","HTML"]:
            self.Listbox[inst].insert(END,items)



    self.submit_button = Button(self, text = "Submit",command = self.returns)
    self.submit_button.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = W)

    self.content = []



def returns(self):
    for inst in result:
        self.content.append(self.Listbox[inst].curselection())
        print self.content


    self.master.destroy()    


root = Tk()

app = Application(master = root)
root.title("Output Formats")
app.mainloop()
print app.content
```

I get only one listbox with this code but I get the selected number of labels
I am stuck after this point. Couldn't get any further. Please help me. Thanks in advance. Please let me know if the info is not clear. I am open to a completely new code as well.

Comment: btw: use dictionary `self.listbox[inst]` in place of `self.("Listbox"+inst)`

Comment: Changed as you said. Edited in my post too. No improvements yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code (with small modifications) works for me.

I don't know why you have a problem.

I put my working code

```
import Tkinter as tk

result = ['Weekly', 'Monthly', 'Annual']

class Application(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.grid()
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.listbox = dict() # lower case for variable name 
        self.label = dict() # lower case for variable name 

        for inst in result:
            #textenter = "Select the required output format" + inst
            textenter = inst

            self.label[inst] = tk.Label(self, text=textenter)
            self.label[inst].grid(columnspan=2, sticky=tk.W)

            self.listbox[inst] = tk.Listbox(self, selectmode=tk.MULTIPLE, exportselection=0)
            self.listbox[inst].grid(sticky=tk.W)

            for items in ["Text", "XML", "HTML"]:
                self.listbox[inst].insert(tk.END,items)

        self.submit_button = tk.Button(self, text="Submit", command=self.returns)
        self.submit_button.grid(row=7, column=1, sticky=tk.W)


    def returns(self):
        self.content = []

        for inst in result:
            self.content.append(self.listbox[inst].curselection())

        print self.content

        self.master.destroy()    


root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(root)
root.title("Output Formats")
app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Its working now. I guess its the row and column number which caused the problem.